# Deleting Dialogflow entity type using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to delete entity types through node.js.
My approach is that, the entity name/s that would be deleted will come from a JSON file. I will then list the existing entities on my agent to find the entity id of the entity to be deleted. Then I will send the request to delete it but nothing's getting deleted.

Here's what I got so far:

```js
//entitytodelete is the JSON file containing the entity name
entitytodelete.forEach(function(entityParams) {
 
entityClient 
.listEntityTypes({parent: projectAgentPath})

// look for entity ID of entity type to be deleted
.then((responses) => { const resources = responses[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {
        const entityTypes = resources[i];
        if (entityTypes.displayName === entityParams) {
          return entityTypes;
        }
      }})
.then((entityParams) => {
console.log('The ID of the entity to delete is: ', JSON.stringify(entityParams.name));

const request = {
    parent: projectAgentPath,
    entityValues    : [entityParams.name],
};
return entityClient.batchDeleteEntityTypes(request);
})
```

Comment: Can you also show a sample JSON value for `entitytodelete`?

Comment: it will just get a simple JSON file such as:
{"Name": ["Sample"]}

I can already get the path of the entity in the loop (entityParams.name) in this format:
"projects/<Project ID>/agent/entityTypes/<Entity ID>"

Comment: If your goal is to delete the entire entity, you should change `entityValues` key to `entityTypeNames` see reference https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow/latest/v2.EntityTypesClient.html#batchDeleteEntityTypes. But let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Did the changing of key worked?

Comment: Yes. It worked. Figured out that I was trying to delete an entity value instead of the entire entity type that's why it was not getting deleted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per conversation with @JoshMcD, changing the key `entityValues` to `entityTypeNames` worked since method [batchDeleteEntityTypes()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow/latest/v2.EntityTypesClient.html#batchDeleteEntityTypes) is **intended to delete an entity type**.

See sample code:

```
const request = {
    parent: projectAgentPath,
    entityTypeNames    : [entityParams.name], 
};
return entityClient.batchDeleteEntityTypes(request);
```